# Arbitrary size of one of the dimensions

Tags: python, keras

When defining own generator function like the following:

```
def generator(features, labels, batch_size):
 # Create empty arrays to contain batch of features and labels#
 batch_features = np.zeros((batch_size, 64, 64, 3))
 batch_labels = np.zeros((batch_size,1))
 while True:
   for i in range(batch_size):
     # choose random index in features
     index= random.choice(len(features),1)
     batch_features[i] = some_processing(features[index])
     batch_labels[i] = labels[index]
   yield batch_features, batch_labels
```

Is there a way to specify that one of the dimensions in the batch_features is arbitrary. So suppose that my batch_size is 32 and that I have 10 different features, but the number of samples is undefined. So I have something like this in mind:

```
np.zeros((32, ,10))
```

i.e. a number of samples can be anything. I know that passing training data into .fit() function in keras only imposes the constraint on the dimensionality and not on the number of samples. Though, I am not certain how to amend the above-given code, to incorporate my requirement.

EDIT:
What I am really interested in thus, is whether I can create something of the form:

```
np.array([1,2,3],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

And it looks like it is not possible to do that.

Comment: What about a list of `np.array`s?

Comment: :) I should take a break. Thanks :) That will work